# update a table field without losing previous data

Tags: database, magento-1

I have a situation in which I need to fill a field of my custom table with new data without losing the existing data. Currently when I submitting data, data exist in this field will get overwritten by new data. Which is the best method to do it?

Below I am providing the necessary details:

- my custom module model : `banner/banner`
- table name : `banner`
- field that I need to update : `images`

Comment: You have to increase the size of the field?

Comment: nope. but in future i need to do it also. how can we achieve this?

Comment: In magento if you want to change the table fileld then you have to write update script in magento.

Comment: okei. can you show me a small demo code for this?

Comment: Give me some time I will prepare for you and explain you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used following code and it worked for me. This code will collect the data from database and store it into a variable.

```
 <?php
     $data = $bannerModel -> getCollection() -> getData();
     $bannerNames=$data[0]['images'];
     /*
          followed by code that collect new data from the form field. 
          Then it will store new data to $bannerNames. 
     /*
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you want to save a part of model. Set value for the column to be updated and save it. Whwn you submitting data try the following.

```
// Assume the images column's value is $value and the id is $id.
$row = Mage::getModel('banner/banner')->load($id)
$row->setImages($value)->save();
```

The above code will only update the 'images' field with the given value. It won't affect to the other fields of that row.